# Hi I am new to Neo4j, I am getting error with cartesian product

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cartesian-product

I am getting error with cartesian product. like I am trying to create a relationship, But it does-not allow me to create relationship instead it says no changes. I am not able to create create relationships how can I solve this issue?

************Here is my code***********

```
MATCH
  (a:Neuron),
  (b:Structure)
WHERE a.doi = "10.1126/science.aah511477" AND a.local_id = 1 AND b.acronym = "SSp-tr"
CREATE (a)-[r:BELONGS_TO]->(b);
```

Comment: did you check a and b are there?  for instance , try this: MATCH (a:Neuron), (b:Structure) WHERE a.doi = "10.1126/science.aah511477" AND a.local_id = 1 AND b.acronym = "SSp-tr" 
    RETURN a,b

Comment: Yes , I already did that, There should be a Relationship created , but says no changes.

Comment: What happens if you extend your original query with 'RETURN  a,r,b   " ?

Comment: It stays the same, It says no changes and remains the same, but says "This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns." in the warning and there is no edge created with is code. @Graphileon

Comment: Maybe it is already created? What do you get when you run: ```MATCH p=(a:Neuron)-[r:BELONGS_TO]-(b:Structure) WHERE a.doi = "10.1126/science.aah511477" RETURN p```

Answer (score 1):

You need to gather Neurons first then Structure before you create the relationships.

```
MATCH (a:Neuron) WHERE a.doi = "10.1126/science.aah511477" AND a.local_id = 1
WITH a
MATCH (b:Structure) WHERE b.acronym = "SSp-tr"
CREATE (a)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(b);
```

The match in line 1 and line 3 can be treated as a cartesian product of a and b.  This is a faster than your original query.

Comment: I tried even this does not work, is there any other way to get rid of cartesian product

Comment: After using this there should be a connection ideally create but it says no changes, and when I check the warning it says cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCZPI.png)

Hi, you should try to test with `MATCH` first to check whether it returns data, because the query you have shown works.

```
MATCH (a:Neuron), (b:Structure) 
WHERE a.doi = "10.1126/science.aah511477" AND a.local_id = 1 AND b.acronym = "SSp-tr" 
RETURN a,b ;
```

Surely you have some difference with the attributes.

Also, if you want to force the relationship to be created, I don't recommend it, you'll create a relationship with `null` nodes, using `OPTIONAL MATCH`

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:Neuron), (b:Structure) 
WHERE a.doi = "10.1126/science.aah511477" AND a.local_id = 1 AND b.acronym = "SSp-tr" 
CREATE (a)-[r:BELONGS_TO]->(b);
```

I hope the answer serves you.

Comment: I already did this as well it says Variable `a` not defined (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"RETURN a,b"

Comment: That means it's not finding the node, because it must have some different attribute.

just do the match

MATCH (a:Neuron) WHERE a.doi = "10.1126/science.aah511477" AND a.local_id = 1  RETURN a

And you will see that it would not have worked.

Alternatively, to prove that you can do the query, create a node with those attributes and run the original query to create the relationship.

Comment: I don't know it is a problem here if i run a small set of code having 4 nodes this code works absolutely fine. but if i have the bigger database created, just imagine i have 12 nodes or more than that, that is when I am facing this warning, once i create more than 12 nodes i fail in creating the relationships and come across cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are naming the right attributes.

Go to Explore and double-click on a node and it will bring up it's attributes. So many times people don't check that it's ID and not Id or NAME vs Name and you won't get a wrong attribute warning - it will just cartesian.